# Calculating conditional entropy

Tags: python, entropy

I'm given:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd

attrNms = ["attr 1", "attr 2", "attr 3", "attr 4", "attr 5"]

data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ],
    columns=attrNms,
)
```

and

```
data["cl"] = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0].
```

I have a function

```
def getConditionalEntropy(cl, attr):
    AssocEnt = np.c_(cl, attr)
    CondEnt = AssocEnt - getEntropy(cl)
    return CondEnt
```

(getEntropy function works correct) but i need function that will calculate conditional entropy of attr and cl according to the formula of conditional entropy: (|)=−∑∈∑∈(,)2((,)/()). Also, if we have 2(0) then it is equal to 0 and if  ()=0, then (,)/() is equal to 0 too. It is clear that x = attr and y = cl. The function should return conditional entropy for one of 5 given attributes.

Comment: Please try to do this first, and then come to stack overflow with more specific issues.

Comment: How can I calculate () and (,)?

Comment: you wrote the formula yourself. You need to make a python function out of that.

Comment: I don't know how so can you help please?

Comment: @Ragna, It will be difficult for members in Stack Overflow to help you solve this without details about the function. The function is your own. So you have to write them. However, what we can help you is to show you how to define a function and how to return values from a function. See these links for additional help: [link to w3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp),  [link to real python](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/),  [link to datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial)